# convert JPEG to XML using SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis, jpeg

I'm trying to convert picture as field in the xml
using SSIS program.
I tried search for it without success ,
if anyone know how it will be a great help.

thanks for the helpers,

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. JPEG is a picture. XML is text. What conversion are you talking about? Are you trying to convert the data to a BASE64 string or something similar?

Comment: I mean convert it into byte array or any kind of structure, and then put it as a field on the xml

Comment: You are going to have to write something to do this, more than likely in a script task. Something that may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776645/insert-image-into-xml-file-using-c-sharp

Comment: @HAy put what in XML? As I said, XML is **text**, you can't just dump image bytes into a text file. If you don't know what you want to produce, you can't use SSIS or any other tool to do it

Comment: as I already said, I want to convert picture into binary/bytes or anything else, so I can put it as a field in XML